# Java - Comparable wiithout generic now?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

For some reason, typing:

```
    class Something<T extends Comparable<T>> {

}
```

Gets an error: *type Comparable does not take parameters*

But writing now:

```
    class Something<T extends Comparable> {

}
```

Does compile. Why? I tried it out on javac version 1.7.0.51. Am I missing something? Or do they have removed that we don't need to type generic param on Comparable?

Comment: I can bet you've another class or interface with the name `Comparable` that is dirtying your classpath. Check for that. Or just for confirming this quick, try changing that `Comparable` to `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: nope, unfortunately not

Comment: maybe because T is both, the object for Something and the Object for Comparable?

Comment: Which java version who are using ??

Comment: @Youngistan looks like 1.7.0.51 according to OP's mention of `javac`.

Comment: [Comparable definitely takes a parameter](http://ideone.com/2ScMc5) so I'd suggest to check again what @RohitJain has suggested.

Comment: I think @RohitJain answer is correct, if you want more help you need to post more context.

Comment: Please update your question with a source file which shows this problem, including explicitly specifying java.lang.Comparable as @RohitJain suggested. Also show the output of `javac -version`